# Terminal stops working after I run a command

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Terminal randomly stops working after I run a command. The input prompt is shown but it will not take any input any more. I tried running ls, but nothing happens.

After I click Terminal > Reset and clear, the screen goes black and the input prompt is not shown at all, just the white cursor, still not accepting any input. See this screenshot:

[image]

I can open another tab which works fine.

EDIT:

Happened again after I ran a `git add` command in a different folder as the one before. I then typed a `git commit -m "message"` command and the shell wouldn't react on my pressing enter. Again I opened another tab with Ctrl+Shift+T and copied my  `git commit` command and it worked. Typing `reset` and Enter in the frozen tab doesn't do anything. So far it seems to be happening randomly.

Bellow is my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export PATH=$PATH:~/custom-bash
```

EDIT:

It could indeed be the Ctrl-S problem. I don't remember pressing this key combination after typing the `git commit` command however pressing Ctrl-Q all of a sudden ran all my typed commands (the Enters I pressed and the `reset` command which reset bash on the tab I think - the tab cleared).

I will come back if this problem occurs and I solve it with Ctrl-Q. I'll also know for sure if I pressed Ctrl-S by accident or if some other process blocked the terminal, if that's possible.

Comment: Does this happen after any command at all? Only specific ones? Either way, it sounds as though you might have set something bad as `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  Please [edit] your question and show us the contents of your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: How can you reproduce? Always on ls? Alway in same directory? Anything in dmesg, like IO errors on disc? Any other problem at the same time?

Comment: Does blindly typing "reset" (and pressing Enter) do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try control Q maybe the command you run has control S

to disable control S all together stick `stty -ixon` in your startup

to enable it again `stty ixon`

Comment: A command run cannot "have" "control S". This is something that can be pressed from the keyboard, but it has no equivalent that an application could output.

Comment: This could indeed be close to the problem. I'll update as soon as I know more. See the last edit.

Comment: Indeed this response could use some rephrasing. I'll mark this as the answer however, as me pressing `Ctrl-S` accidentally (while trying to save a file in another window or such) is most likely the cause. More info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/how-to-unfreeze-after-accidentally-pressing-ctrl-s-in-a-terminal).

Comment: Thank you, i should get +1 instead of -1 then for the answer :)